# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND for Enjoyhint Plugin

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/hints-creation-with-enjoyhint/) to create a first time user guide. I followed the guide and installed EnjoyHint, however I am getting these error message:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND casino_hand-webfont.woff
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND casino_hand-webfont.ttf
```

I imported the stylesheet and javascript as:

```
<link href="bower_components/enjoyhint/enjoyhint.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="bower_components/enjoyhint/enjoyhint.min.js"></script>
```

They are in the correct folder but I not sure why am I getting the message above.

My JavaScript code:

```
var enjoyhint_instance = new EnjoyHint({});
var enjoyhint_script_steps = [{
    'click #tab_1' : 'This button allows you to switch between the search results'
}, {

}];
enjoyhint_instance.set(enjoyhint_script_steps);
enjoyhint_instance.run();
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not the plugin files are missing, but some fonts. Did you make sure to put those in the correct folder, as well?

Comment: Yeap because I installed the plugin with command prompt and it comes together in a folder

Comment: I also think the files are missing because of their path...

Comment: @Aria But I located the file and there are in the correct folder as specified in the path

Comment: @hyperfkcb can you share a screen shot of your solution ?

Comment: @Aria Updated question! Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, Take a photo of your environment and update your question I want just see your solutions folders? something like [this](http://johnatten.com/wp-content/uploads/imported/cloned-solution-in-vs-solution-explorer_thumb.png) , just make sure all the sub-folders are expanded before taking photo.

Comment: @Aria Updated question!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161594/discussion-between-aria-and-hyperfkcb).